# Find string in nested object array in object array

Tags: javascript

I have the following object array:

```
let options = [
    { 'row': 1, 'colors': [{'hex': '#7484ad', 'friendly': 'Nudget Blue'}, {'hex': '#32db64', 'friendly': 'Green'}, {'hex':'#910d9b', 'friendly': 'Dark Magenta'}, {'hex': '#b00908', 'friendly': 'Dark Red'}] },
    { 'row': 2, 'colors': [{'hex': '#2bc6d1', 'friendly': 'Cyan'}, {'hex': '#216d0b', 'friendly': 'Dark Green'}, {'hex': '#d88219', 'friendly': 'Orange'}, {'hex': '#ed48c6', 'friendly': 'Pink'}] },
    { 'row': 3, 'colors': [{'hex': '#0e0e49', 'friendly': 'Dark Blue'}, {'hex': '#5b5b5b', 'friendly': 'Dark Gray'}, {'hex': '#000000', 'friendly': 'Black'}, {'hex': '#1213dd', 'friendly': 'Blue'}] }
]
```

I'd like to get a color's friendly name by it's corresponding hex value.

So far I've tried:

```
console.log(options.find(color => color.colors.hex == '#910d9b'))
```

However, this gives me an error:

```
Property 'hex' does not exist on type '{ 'hex': string; 'friendly': string; }[]'.
```

How can I find the hex value's friendly name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `colors` value is an array, so it doesn't have a `hex` property - only an individual `color` *inside* the `colors` array will have a `hex` property.

Because you don't want to end up with the *row*, but the friendly name, it would probably be more appropriate to use `reduce` rather than `.find`, otherwise you'll have to `.find` *once* to find the right row with the correct color, and then again to get the color and its `friendly` out of the row.

```js
let options = [
    { 'row': 1, 'colors': [{'hex': '#7484ad', 'friendly': 'Nudget Blue'}, {'hex': '#32db64', 'friendly': 'Green'}, {'hex':'#910d9b', 'friendly': 'Dark Magenta'}, {'hex': '#b00908', 'friendly': 'Dark Red'}] },
    { 'row': 2, 'colors': [{'hex': '#2bc6d1', 'friendly': 'Cyan'}, {'hex': '#216d0b', 'friendly': 'Dark Green'}, {'hex': '#d88219', 'friendly': 'Orange'}, {'hex': '#ed48c6', 'friendly': 'Pink'}] },
    { 'row': 3, 'colors': [{'hex': '#0e0e49', 'friendly': 'Dark Blue'}, {'hex': '#5b5b5b', 'friendly': 'Dark Gray'}, {'hex': '#000000', 'friendly': 'Black'}, {'hex': '#1213dd', 'friendly': 'Blue'}] }
];
const result = options.reduce((a, { colors }) => {
  if (a) return a;
  const found = colors.find(({ hex }) => hex === '#910d9b');
  if (found) return found.friendly;
}, null);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first make a combined flatten array of the colors value and then find the friendly color in the result based on the hex value.

```js
function findFriendly(options, hex){
  return [].concat(...options.map(option => option.colors))
           .find(color => color.hex === hex).friendly;
}

let options = [
    { 'row': 1, 'colors': [{'hex': '#7484ad', 'friendly': 'Nudget Blue'}, {'hex': '#32db64', 'friendly': 'Green'}, {'hex':'#910d9b', 'friendly': 'Dark Magenta'}, {'hex': '#b00908', 'friendly': 'Dark Red'}] },
    { 'row': 2, 'colors': [{'hex': '#2bc6d1', 'friendly': 'Cyan'}, {'hex': '#216d0b', 'friendly': 'Dark Green'}, {'hex': '#d88219', 'friendly': 'Orange'}, {'hex': '#ed48c6', 'friendly': 'Pink'}] },
    { 'row': 3, 'colors': [{'hex': '#0e0e49', 'friendly': 'Dark Blue'}, {'hex': '#5b5b5b', 'friendly': 'Dark Gray'}, {'hex': '#000000', 'friendly': 'Black'}, {'hex': '#1213dd', 'friendly': 'Blue'}] }
];

console.log(findFriendly(options, "#d88219"));
console.log(findFriendly(options, "#1213dd"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a vanilla answer that should be fast. It'll return a result immediately once a match is found, unlike `reduce`, and doesn't require any preprocessing or flattening.

```js
let options = [
    { 'row': 1, 'colors': [{'hex': '#7484ad', 'friendly': 'Nudget Blue'}, {'hex': '#32db64', 'friendly': 'Green'}, {'hex':'#910d9b', 'friendly': 'Dark Magenta'}, {'hex': '#b00908', 'friendly': 'Dark Red'}] },
    { 'row': 2, 'colors': [{'hex': '#2bc6d1', 'friendly': 'Cyan'}, {'hex': '#216d0b', 'friendly': 'Dark Green'}, {'hex': '#d88219', 'friendly': 'Orange'}, {'hex': '#ed48c6', 'friendly': 'Pink'}] },
    { 'row': 3, 'colors': [{'hex': '#0e0e49', 'friendly': 'Dark Blue'}, {'hex': '#5b5b5b', 'friendly': 'Dark Gray'}, {'hex': '#000000', 'friendly': 'Black'}, {'hex': '#1213dd', 'friendly': 'Blue'}] }
];

const findFriendly = (a, hex) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    const idx = a[i].colors.findIndex(e => e.hex === '#910d9b');
    if (idx >= 0) { return a[i].colors[idx].friendly; }
  }
}

console.log(findFriendly(options, '#910d9b'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think simple is better in this case. Loop through the rows and look for the color. This allows the option of exiting early if you find the color right away.

```js
let options = [
    { 'row': 1, 'colors': [{'hex': '#7484ad', 'friendly': 'Nudget Blue'}, {'hex': '#32db64', 'friendly': 'Green'}, {'hex':'#910d9b', 'friendly': 'Dark Magenta'}, {'hex': '#b00908', 'friendly': 'Dark Red'}] },
    { 'row': 2, 'colors': [{'hex': '#2bc6d1', 'friendly': 'Cyan'}, {'hex': '#216d0b', 'friendly': 'Dark Green'}, {'hex': '#d88219', 'friendly': 'Orange'}, {'hex': '#ed48c6', 'friendly': 'Pink'}] },
    { 'row': 3, 'colors': [{'hex': '#0e0e49', 'friendly': 'Dark Blue'}, {'hex': '#5b5b5b', 'friendly': 'Dark Gray'}, {'hex': '#000000', 'friendly': 'Black'}, {'hex': '#1213dd', 'friendly': 'Blue'}] }
]

function findColor(hex, options){ // returns undefined if not found
    for (row of options){
        let color = row.colors.find(obj => obj.hex === hex)
        if (color) return color.friendly
    }
}

let f = findColor('#5b5b5b', options)
console.log(f)
```